# How to use swift's firstIndex to generate a new subarray?

Tags: ios, swift

For example, I have array `let candidates=["1","0","a","b","c"]` , and I want to return `["a","b","c"]`

Here's the code:

```swift
if let head = candidates.firstIndex(of: "0") {
    return candidates[head..<candidates.count]
}
```

But got error: `No 'subscript' candidates produce the expected contextual result type '[String]'`

Comment: Does your function expect to return type `[String]`? `candidates[head..<candidates.count]` will return type `ArraySlice` so if you want to convert that to an array, you might need to do `Array(candidates[head..<candidates.count])`

Comment: @ShawnFrank You made my day. Please make it as an answer, in that case I could accept it.

Comment: Done and also added one addition to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your function expect to return type `[String]`?

`candidates[head..<candidates.count]` will return type `ArraySlice` so if you want to convert that to an `array`, you might need to do

`return Array(candidates[head..<candidates.count])`

One more small addition for completeness, since you want to return `["a","b","c"]`, you will need to start from the index **after** "0" so I would do:

`return Array(candidates[head+1..<candidates.count])`